# SwiftUI preview not building for different scheme: error: no such module 'MyApp'

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have an app that is mainly built using UIKit, but I've just added my first SwiftUI view but it's not building. There are two different schemes within my Xcode project: `MyApp` and `MyApp_Staging`. I am working in the `MyApp_Staging` scheme and wanting to see what my SwiftUI preview looks like. However, it won't build and gives me the error:

```
    no such module 'MyApp'

----------------------------------------

CompileDylibError: Failed to build ImagePickerView.swift

Compiling failed: no such module 'MyApp'

/Users/Me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-czotsuriazmotwgvkpfocaqlgfpz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Previews/MyApp (Staging)/Intermediates.noindex/MyApp.build/Debug (Staging)-iphonesimulator/MyApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ImagePickerView.2.preview-thunk.swift:1:55: error: no such module 'MyApp'
@_private(sourceFile: "ImagePickerView.swift") import MyApp
```

I know the schemes are set up correctly as the app usually works normally.

In my Product Module Name, it correctly lists multiple values: MyApp and MyApp_staging for the different build types. Technically, the value is set as `$(PRODUCT_NAME:c99extidentifier)` but this fills in the correct name.

What is causing this issue?

Comment: Same problem here, did you found any solution ?

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't a solution - it doesn't like different schemes. So you have to select the main scheme, which in my case would be `MyApp` rather than the staging one when building previews

Comment: This is very frustating

Answer (score 2):

After a few hours of frustrating I manage to find the problem that cause the preview not to show up and error like you mention above.

This question has been asked for long time ago, but I hope at least someone that facing this problem might get some clue or answer, so I'm gonna leave it here.

In my case I've 3 separate target schema Debug, UAT and Production, I've tries switching target between 3 of them but I notice that when I switch to my production scheme it work perfectly fine, the preview show normally without error, and then I realize it might relate to the target schema.

So I check in my **Project Target > Build Settings > Packaging > Product Name**

There are Debug, Release, UAT - Debug and UAT - Release, all with the same Target name, only UAT Debug is name different from other scheme, so I change that UAT - Debug product name to match the target name, and it work normal now

I don't know if you face the same problem like me or not, but this actually solved my problem, but what I don't understand is that, that configuration has been leave like that since the project has been started but there's no error, I've use preview normally without problem, it's just today the error show up.

Comment: Thanks, your answer just saved me hours of frustrating debugging... My target name had a space and a dot in the name... apparently preview doesn't like that at all. I renamed my target (no dot, no space any more( which fortunately worked without a hiccup and then overwrote the module name with the same string as the target name for both debug and release... Then finally, preview worked again.